# How to change tabSize and insertSpaces in vscode

Tags: whitespace, indentation, visual-studio-code

How do you actually go about changing the "editor.tabSize" and "editor.insertSpaces" values for vscode? I've opened File > Preferences > User Settings and added:

```json
    // Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
    // Controls the rendering size of tabs in characters. If set to auto, the value will be guessed based on the opened file.
    "editor.tabSize": 4,

    // Controls if the editor will insert spaces for tabs. If set to auto, the value will be guessed based on the opened file.
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,
}
```

However, when I open an html file with two-space tabs, pressing tab inserts two spaces, and when I open a file that uses \t tabs, pressing tab inserts \t.

What am I doing wrong that causes vscode to not respect my settings?

Comment: FYI to others, .editorconfig files are [now supported](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7758189-support-editorconfig) in VSCode (via [Editor Config extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/chrisdias.vscodeEditorConfig) presently until merged into core). I prefer this over the .vscode specific workspace settings when possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a trailing comma in your snippet and currently VSCode fails to understand settings with malformed JSON. I am happy to say that with the next update, this issue should be fixed :)!

The working version of settings is:

```json
    // Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
    // Controls the rendering size of tabs in characters. If set to auto, the value will be guessed based on the opened file.
    "editor.tabSize": 4,

    // Controls if the editor will insert spaces for tabs. If set to auto, the value will be guessed based on the opened file.
    "editor.insertSpaces": true
}
```

Comment: First of all, bah! Thank you. Secondly, this did solve my problem, but the editor acted pretty funky for the first few edits. With the settings at 4 spaces always, it acted as if it was set to 2 spaces for xml files, 4 spaces for python files, and auto for html files. I restarted the app, and it still behaved this way, so I set it to 8 spaces and then xml was 6 space tabs, python was 8 space tabs, and html was tab character tabs (auto). Closing the files and reopening seemed to fix the issues. Again, it worked, just saying you might believe it didn't the first twelve or so tries.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, can you report this as an issue with steps to reproduce? There is an entry from the help menu to report. Thanks!

Comment: and it even shows error in ctrl+shift+m and red squiggly underlines the extra comma or the next brace but hard to see, thanks

Comment: I also had an issue where the "editor.tabSize" setting was being ignored - I had set it to 2 but autoformat kept inserting 4 spaces. I found that by setting "editor.detectIndentation" to false, it would use my stored settings.